# Node.JS и файловое хранилище

Tags: node.js

Использую для тестирования сайта Heroku, сайт на Node.JS (Express).
С помощью команд `fs` сохраняю картинки в файлах, но на Heroku они со временем пропадают.
Насколько я понял, для этого используют отдельные файловые хранилища, но я не пойму, как сделать взаимосвязь с ними?
Как сохранять туда картинки и брать их оттуда (пути к картинкам хранятся в Mongo)?

Comment: Ответы на все ваши вопросы есть в документации к файловому хранилищу, которое вы используете.